# Access pushState state object content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var nextUrl = 'page1.html';
        var previousUrl = window.location.href;

        $.get(nextUrl, function(data){
            $('body').html(data);
            history.pushState({content: data}, '', nextUrl); <--How to retrieve the content data
        });
    });
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
        console.log(e.state.content);
        //How do I get the data stored in pushState?
    });
});
</script>
```

I have stored the entire page information in state `pushState({content:data}..`, but how do I retrieve it inside `popstate`?

Thanks!

Comment: What about storing `data` into a global var?

Answer (score 1):

you will get using below line

```
window.history.state['content']
```

Answer (score 1):

The popstate event is fired on window when the active history entry changes. Most commonly when the browsers back or forward buttons are clicked (or a call to back(), forward() or go() is executed).

The event passed into the listener callback contains a state property that is used to retrieve the state object that is associated with the history entry.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  var state = event.state;
});
```

It’s worth noting that calls to pushState() and replaceState() will not trigger a popstate event.

Chrome and Safari will fire a popstate event when the page loads but Firefox doesn’t.